# Restoring WinForm with textbox containing large amount of data

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, restore, repaint

I have created a form in C# (VS2010) which contain (among other) a textbox control.
The textbox may contain large amount of data at some point (~3 million chars).

When scrolling or moving the form around no problems are encountered, but when the form is minimized and restored back again, a repaint sequence (I believe) is triggered which causes a big lag of around 5-10 seconds for the form to be repainted.

I've already tried several solutions:

1. Using double buffer – according to what I've read, double buffering applies only to the form itself and not to its controls

   `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);`
   `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);`
   `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);`
2. Disabling the textbox redrew once minimized using: `SendMessage(this.my_textBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);`
   and enabling back after form is restored. I've noticed that the form repaint lag exist also if I **don't re-enable the textbox repaint**.
3. Manual double buffer using a bitmap – similar results as #1.

I read somewhere that this issue might be related to the textbox control trying to shrink or adjust to the amount of data, but couldn't override it.

I previously had the same project in MFC, but didn't encounter any repaint or lagging issues there.

Please advise me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Set the WordWrap property to False.  It is expensive.

Comment: WordWrap is essential for my purposes. Besides, i don't encounter any repaint issue while the textbox is being updated, or form moved around - only when window is restored from minimize state.

Comment: Well, you asked for advice.  Not taking it was the expected outcome.

Comment: In the sample I made using the overridden textbox below with 3MB of text, word wrap was on and restoring was immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!!! Issue was related to the textbox Anchor property. once i removed it, window restore was immediate. BTW, the new custom class isn't required

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I'm not understanding something (or maybe there's a reason you can't do this), but can't you just derive your own TextBox class as so?

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, false); 
    }
}
```

And then use it in place of a regular textbox?

Comment: I tried this solution, but nothing is changed, when window is restored the entire form in being repainted including the textbox

Comment: Then there's something else going on in your form. If you place this textbox on a form and put 3MB of text into it and minimize and restore, it will happen immediately. Try minimizing and restoring and while it's hanging do a Debug/Break All and see what the stack trace is.

Comment: Found the problem!!!

Issue was related to the textbox Anchor property. once i removed it, window restore was immediate. BTW, the new custom class isn't required